# How to git-commit from a branch to a detached HEAD?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-detached-head, git-dangling

My *ref* `HEAD` points the branch `foo`, that points to the commit `123abc`; and I have some staged work.

How to `git commit` that work, moving the `HEAD` to the newly created commit, but **without advancing the branch**?

(hence: leaving `foo` point to `123abc`)

Is it possible to do it with a single `git` command?

Comment: [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61475780/1256452) is fine, but out of curiosity, *why* do you want to do this? (It's more typical to do `git checkout -b newbranch; git commit` so that the name `newbranch` remembers the new commit for you.)

Comment: That's exactly what I do **not** want. I've ideated a workflow for myself, where I want to be able to make a *"backup commit"* on my development fork, but not on the branch itself. After the detached commit, I just `git tag BAK-change-foobar-schema` and push it.  – This way I can backup my current work **without** making my development branch "dirty" (and without having to `push force` over it, after `git-reset`ting the backup & continuing & committing the definitive commit). – So I know that my branch has just "real" `commit`ments and doesn't contain WIP code.

Comment: Ah: you want to commit so that you can tag the commit (use a tag to remember the hash ID). That's fine, but note that you can also `git checkout -b temp; git commit; git tag ...; git checkout master; git branch -D temp` for instance. Your branch names are *yours* so you can do anything you like with them. The detach-and-commit-and-tag is short and useful, though; it's the kind of thing that you can put in a script, or a Git alias.

Comment: (Everyone I know just uses a private development branch, though. There's a pretty good reason to avoid tag names in a *shared* repository: the tag names get copied to other clones, whereas the branch names just become remote-tracking names that people can ignore. Obviously this doesn't apply to a *private* repository.)

Comment: Yes, but I don't like the maintenance of that `temp` branch  (I tend to forget dirt around), the `--detach` option helps with that; and I usually try to avoid aliases (that I don't get, for example, on remote systems). –  The way I see that, this commit should just not be in the branch in the first place (or on a branch at all); it's just a backup: a commit that stores code but should have no historical meaning.

Comment: Again, yes, you are right. This is indeed contextual to a fork/private repository that I can play with, push personal/dirty tags and eventually rewrite history without worrying of affecting other devs. – When the branch is "more ready and stable" then I push it in the real branch on the shared repository. Before that moment, I can rewrite wildly as I need 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply detach, then commit:

```
git checkout --detach
git commit -m "Commit as usual"
```

Comment: I knew that!  I was having that `detach` option in mind but couldn't find it on `man git-commit`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `HEAD` is directly pointing to commit `123abc`, it's already on detached HEAD state instead of on `foo`. `git commit` will create a new commit and move `HEAD` to the new commit, leaving `foo` unmoved.

If `HEAD` points at `refs/heads/foo` and `refs/heads/foo` points at `123abc`, you can run `git checkout 123abc` and then make the commit.

Comment: yes, you are right, I should fix the question and mean that `HEAD` points to the branch `foo`, rather than the commit itself directly.

Comment: Good answer, but I chose the one from @Quentin since it allows to do what I ask without having to know the `refs` or commit SHA. Thank you tho!

Answer (score 0):

You could just commit and then do a reset:

```
# from foo branch
git commit -m 'your work here'
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

This would move the HEAD pointer back one commit to `123abc`, but would also stage all the work in that commit.

There are other types of reset (mixed, hard), which do variants of the above.  Without knowing your end goal, it isn't clear what kind of reset you should use.  In general, though, moving the HEAD back one commit is something you would do if you wanted to rewrite the prior HEAD commit.

Comment: Yes, that's legit, and is what I usually do, thanks. In this case I was specifically requesting about committing *without advancing the branch*. I was looking for what's described from @Quentin 's answer.